# Login page issue in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I recently tried to develop a simple web app using `Streamlit`. I can create it easily and quickly but I have a problem when I want to create an authentication or login page as I try to deploy it in `Heroku` (free dyno). At first, I thought it was a success until I realize the web app keeps iterating all the codes over after having interaction with the app. Then, I tried to apply `subprocess` but I think due to Heroku policy I cannot spawn another dyno.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

This is what I have done so far:

```py
import streamlit as st
import subprocess

def id_authenticated(username):
    return username == "******"

def pw_authenticated(password):
    return password == "*****"

def generate_login_block():
    block1 = st.empty()
    block2 = st.empty()
    block3 = st.empty()
    block4 = st.empty()
    return block1, block2, block3, block4

def clean_blocks(blocks):
    for block in blocks:
        block.empty()

def login(blocks):
    blocks[0].markdown("""
        <style>
            input {
                -webkit-text-security: none;
            }
        </style>
        """, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    blocks[0].markdown("""
        <style>
            input {
                -webkit-text-security: none;
            }
        </style>
        """, unsafe_allow_html=True)

    return blocks[1].text_input("Username:"), blocks[3].text_input('Password:', value = "", type = "password")

login_blocks = generate_login_block()
username, password = login(login_blocks)
login_button = st.button("Log In")


if login_button & id_authenticated(username) & pw_authenticated(password):
    st.success("You are logged in")
    subprocess.Popen(["streamlit", "run", "app.py"])
elif login_button:
    st.error("Please input valid username and/or password")
```